# Como alterar o foco da webcam durante stream?

Tags: javascript, html5, qrcode

Estou criando um sistema de ponto eletrônico baseado em QrCode e acabei travando porque não consigo focar o QrCode quando estou num celular por exemplo. Digo isso porque na webcam existe a possibilidade de focar para longe ou perto girando a tela dela, no celular preciso fazer isso via software.

Estou utilizando a API QCodeDecode do Ciro Costa que usa html5 e acredito que ele use o getUserMedia para o stream:
http://cirocosta.github.io/qcode-decoder/

Mas não achei nada para alterar o foco da câmera como javascript...

Acredito que não seja impossível, existem apps leitores de QrCode que fazem o autofoco com a câmera do android.

Comment: Não creio que haja uma API estável ou suporte em JS para fazer focus na camara. O FF tem o [`CameraControl.autoFocus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CameraControl.autoFocus) mas nõ é cross-browser.

Comment: É, eu li sobre o Firefox OS e vi essa api, mas realmente não serve se não é cross...